# Why do i get a "404 not found" error on IE(not Chrome) in node.js express? and how to solve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, internet-explorer, express

I'm making web server with node.js and express module.

So, I installed node.js, express and express-generator.

And I completed a prototype web server for my project yesterday.

But, when I tested my prototype, I have a strong question.

In Chrome, I could connect for URL like '127.0.0.1:3000'

or '172.30.5.164:3000'(this is my intranet ip address).

But!!

In Explorer, I could't connect!!

So, I tried to find the way.

I solved the 127.0.0.1:3000 problem.

Just I changed Explorer configuration for intranet and I could connect

like this way 'http://localhost:3000'

However,

I didn't find the way how to connect use URL like http://172.30.5.164:3000

I don't use socket.io module, just use basic express-generator template like GET/POST way.

I need how to connect on IE strongly because my project is related to OLE Automation, So I have to use ActiveXObject.

Anyone who give me the hint?

I'm not good at english writing, so i got to worry about that you understand my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I ........ I solved it.

Comment: Just..... My mistake. from http://172.30.5.164:3000// to http://172.30.5.164:3000/.

Comment: // -> / this proble is from number of '/'

Comment: please move the comments to an individual answer so that it helps other people with the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There is a strange way IE handles local ip
[see article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/262981).